# How to export multiple queries to one excel file with worksheets via SSRS by schedule?

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I would like to extract multiple queries from one database and export to one excel file with worksheets via SSRS by setting schedule.

Could you help to advise how to do it?

If having another more easy solution to perform this task, could you help advise more details for me?

Many Thanks

Ruby

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are all basic functions that are done with SSRS.

For multiple queries, you would want a separate **Dataset** for each query that you want the results in your Excel file.

[SSRS Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/report-datasets-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

To display your data in a worksheet, you would want a separate **table** for each of the **datasets**. You would want a **Page Break** at the End of each table so that each table shows data on a separate tab in Excel. You can also set the **Page Name** property to name the tab in Excel.

[SSRS Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/tables-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

As far as the schedule goes, once you deploy the report to the report server, you can set a **Subscription** so the report is e-mailed or generated to a folder on a set schedule.

[SSRS Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/new-subscription-or-edit-subscription-page-report-manager?view=sql-server-2014)